# how to drag and resize canvas rectangle using cursor types

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

In a canvas, I have drawn a rectangle and done drag and resize functionalities. Circles are drawn to represent handles to resize the rectangle. But now i want to drag using cursor types.

I have used cursor type as below:

```
$("#canvas").css({'cursor':'ne-resize'});
```

here is the jsfiddle link.
 http://jsfiddle.net/BaliBalo/9HXMG/

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    rect = {
        x: 150,
        y: 100,
        w: 123,
        h: 58
    },
    handlesSize = 8,
    currentHandle = false,
    drag = false;

function init() {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
}

function point(x, y) {
    return {
        x: x,
        y: y
    };
}

function dist(p1, p2) {
    return Math.sqrt((p2.x - p1.x) * (p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y) * (p2.y - p1.y));
}

function getHandle(mouse) {
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x, rect.y)) <= handlesSize) return 'topleft';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w, rect.y)) <= handlesSize) return 'topright';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x, rect.y + rect.h)) <= handlesSize) return 'bottomleft';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w, rect.y + rect.h)) <= handlesSize) return 'bottomright';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w / 2, rect.y)) <= handlesSize) return 'top';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x, rect.y + rect.h / 2)) <= handlesSize) return 'left';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w / 2, rect.y + rect.h)) <= handlesSize) return 'bottom';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w, rect.y + rect.h / 2)) <= handlesSize) return 'right';
    return false;
}

function mouseDown(e) {
    if (currentHandle) drag = true;
    draw();
}

function mouseUp() {
    drag = false;
    currentHandle = false;
    draw();
}

function mouseMove(e) {
    var previousHandle = currentHandle;
    if (!drag) currentHandle = getHandle(point(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop));
    if (currentHandle && drag) {
        var mousePos = point(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
        switch (currentHandle) {
            case 'topleft':
                rect.w += rect.x - mousePos.x;
                rect.h += rect.y - mousePos.y;
                rect.x = mousePos.x;
                rect.y = mousePos.y;
                break;
            case 'topright':
                rect.w = mousePos.x - rect.x;
                rect.h += rect.y - mousePos.y;
                rect.y = mousePos.y;
                break;
            case 'bottomleft':
                rect.w += rect.x - mousePos.x;
                rect.x = mousePos.x;
                rect.h = mousePos.y - rect.y;
                break;
            case 'bottomright':
                rect.w = mousePos.x - rect.x;
                rect.h = mousePos.y - rect.y;
                break;

            case 'top':
                rect.h += rect.y - mousePos.y;
                rect.y = mousePos.y;
                break;

            case 'left':
                rect.w += rect.x - mousePos.x;
                rect.x = mousePos.x;
                break;

            case 'bottom':
                rect.h = mousePos.y - rect.y;
                break;

            case 'right':
                rect.w = mousePos.x - rect.x;
                break;
        }
    }
    if (drag || currentHandle != previousHandle) draw();
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h);
    if (currentHandle) {
        var posHandle = point(0, 0);
        switch (currentHandle) {
            case 'topleft':
                posHandle.x = rect.x;
                posHandle.y = rect.y;
                break;
            case 'topright':
                posHandle.x = rect.x + rect.w;
                posHandle.y = rect.y;
                break;
            case 'bottomleft':
                posHandle.x = rect.x;
                posHandle.y = rect.y + rect.h;
                break;
            case 'bottomright':
                posHandle.x = rect.x + rect.w;
                posHandle.y = rect.y + rect.h;
                break;
            case 'top':
                posHandle.x = rect.x + rect.w / 2;
                posHandle.y = rect.y;
                break;
            case 'left':
                posHandle.x = rect.x;
                posHandle.y = rect.y + rect.h / 2;
                break;
            case 'bottom':
                posHandle.x = rect.x + rect.w / 2;
                posHandle.y = rect.y + rect.h;
                break;
            case 'right':
                posHandle.x = rect.x + rect.w;
                posHandle.y = rect.y + rect.h / 2;
                break;
        }
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(posHandle.x, posHandle.y, handlesSize, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    }
}

init();
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the wanted cursor type in the swicth statement of your `draw` function :

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    rect = {
        x: 150,
        y: 100,
        w: 123,
        h: 58
    },
    handlesSize = 8,
    currentHandle = false,
    drag = false;

function init() {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
}

function point(x, y) {
    return {
        x: x,
        y: y
    };
}

function dist(p1, p2) {
    return Math.sqrt((p2.x - p1.x) * (p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y) * (p2.y - p1.y));
}

function getHandle(mouse) {
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x, rect.y)) <= handlesSize) return 'topleft';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w, rect.y)) <= handlesSize) return 'topright';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x, rect.y + rect.h)) <= handlesSize) return 'bottomleft';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w, rect.y + rect.h)) <= handlesSize) return 'bottomright';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w / 2, rect.y)) <= handlesSize) return 'top';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x, rect.y + rect.h / 2)) <= handlesSize) return 'left';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w / 2, rect.y + rect.h)) <= handlesSize) return 'bottom';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w, rect.y + rect.h / 2)) <= handlesSize) return 'right';
    return false;
}

function mouseDown(e) {
    if (currentHandle) drag = true;
    draw();
}

function mouseUp() {
    drag = false;
    currentHandle = false;
    draw();
}

function mouseMove(e) {
    var previousHandle = currentHandle;
    if (!drag) currentHandle = getHandle(point(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop));
    if (currentHandle && drag) {
        var mousePos = point(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
        switch (currentHandle) {
            case 'topleft':
                rect.w += rect.x - mousePos.x;
                rect.h += rect.y - mousePos.y;
                rect.x = mousePos.x;
                rect.y = mousePos.y;
                break;
            case 'topright':
                rect.w = mousePos.x - rect.x;
                rect.h += rect.y - mousePos.y;
                rect.y = mousePos.y;
                break;
            case 'bottomleft':
                rect.w += rect.x - mousePos.x;
                rect.x = mousePos.x;
                rect.h = mousePos.y - rect.y;
                break;
            case 'bottomright':
                rect.w = mousePos.x - rect.x;
                rect.h = mousePos.y - rect.y;
                break;

            case 'top':
                rect.h += rect.y - mousePos.y;
                rect.y = mousePos.y;
                break;

            case 'left':
                rect.w += rect.x - mousePos.x;
                rect.x = mousePos.x;
                break;

            case 'bottom':
                rect.h = mousePos.y - rect.y;
                break;

            case 'right':
                rect.w = mousePos.x - rect.x;
                break;
        }
    }
    if (drag || currentHandle != previousHandle) draw();


}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h);
    if (currentHandle) {
        var posHandle = point(0, 0);
        var dir;
        switch (currentHandle) {
            case 'topleft':
                dir={x:rect.w>0?'w':'e',y:rect.h>0?'n':'s'};
                canvas.style.cursor= dir.y+dir.x+'-resize';
                break;
            case 'topright':
                dir={x:rect.w>0?'e':'w',y:rect.h>0?'n':'s'};
                canvas.style.cursor= dir.y+dir.x+'-resize';
                break;
            case 'bottomleft':
                dir={x:rect.w>0?'w':'e',y:rect.h>0?'s':'n'};
                canvas.style.cursor= dir.y+dir.x+'-resize';
                break;
            case 'bottomright':
                dir={x:rect.w>0?'e':'w',y:rect.h>0?'s':'n'};
                canvas.style.cursor= dir.y+dir.x+'-resize';
                break;
            case 'top':
                canvas.style.cursor= (rect.h>0?'n':'s')+'-resize';
                break;
            case 'left':
                canvas.style.cursor= (rect.w>0?'w':'e')+'-resize';
                break;
            case 'bottom':
                canvas.style.cursor= (rect.h>0?'s':'n')+'-resize';
                break;
            case 'right':
                canvas.style.cursor= (rect.w>0?'e':'w')+'-resize';
                break;
        }
    }else canvas.style.cursor='';
}

init();
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido.This has been done by me also.In this case whether you have check the cursor type after dragging the rect in negative direction.I have run ur code snippet.Initially the cursor drawn for topright position is crct.but when you have to drag all sides after that you have check that direction is wrong.can you please check this.I am asking this

Comment: i have done that.I am having another doubt.I am having chart.In chart area,i have drawn the rect while moving the mouse.based on that id we can set the cursor types.so now move the cursor outside of the rect means,default cursor shown.how to resolve that.I am having rect and all the corners having small rects that are invisible.based on the small rect we can drag using cursors.when it moves from that id default cursor shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to change the cursor type, put this in your html in a style tag or in a css file linked to your html

```
#canvas{ cursor: ne-resize}
```

or to do this with javascript

```
document.getElementById("canvas").style.cursor = "ne-resize";
```

The code you have `$("#canvas").css({'cursor':'ne-resize'});` is jQuery. In order for that to work, you need to link the library in your head tag.

Comment: Thanks for ur response.actually i have set cursor types in rect.but when dragging the rect in 360 degree,in negative side getting wrong handle thats why the cursor not set correctly.If you in fiddle link u can understand what i m asking