# I want the man to switch to a mouse pointer when it is near the circle

Tags: javascript, html

my problem is that i can't switch to a mouse pointer when it is near the circle or directly above it. The mouse should be normal when it is not near or above the circle. In addition, I want you to be able to pull from the circle and the stretch to act as a rubber band.

Edit; I want to move the line in the center with clicking to the circle in the middle. The code is shown above

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// den gule 
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,0)";
ctx.fillRect(27, 50, 450, 430);

// den rød firkekant
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(249,35,2)";
ctx.fillRect(170, 180, 160, 130);

// strekken
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(170, 245);
ctx.lineTo(330, 245);
ctx.stroke();

// sirkel 
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(250, 245, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Strikk oppgave</title>

<body>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

I want to move the line in the center with clicking to the circle in the middle. The code is shown above

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After looking around at a lot of documentation, I found it easy to find articles on changing the cursor type based on scroll position. Consider this jQuery:

```
$("body").mousemove(function(e){
if (e.pageX > 250 && e.pageY > 240 && e.pageX < 270 && e.pageY < 260)
    $("body").css("cursor", "pointer");
else
    $("body").css("cursor", "default");
});
```

However, finding the part on resizing the circle on a mouse drag is much harder. You could use a Konva.js circle instead of a canvas arc, as you'll see on one of the three recommended links I have below:

[Is there a way to resize a circle by dragging the circumference outward / inward using Konva js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53261699/is-there-a-way-to-resize-a-circle-by-dragging-the-circumference-outward-inward)

[how to drag and resize canvas rectangle using cursor types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390028/how-to-drag-and-resize-canvas-rectangle-using-cursor-types)

[HTML Canvas draw a circle on mouse click and drag it untill the required radius is obtained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33811677/html-canvas-draw-a-circle-on-mouse-click-and-drag-it-untill-the-required-radius)

You'll just have to modify the code in these links according to your needs, as this is all I was able to really come up with.

Comment: Put the following code before your <head></head> tags, which goes right before the <body></body> tags: <style> #myCanvas:hover { cursor: pointer; } </style>

Comment: But i want to mouse pointer only when i am around the circle and not the entire page. There is a small circle in the center. I want to  have mouse pinter when hover over that.

Comment: I see. I must have misread your question. I'll get an edit for you soon.

Comment: Oki nice. So when you ONLY hover over the circle in the middle in the yellow square then the cursor should change to pointing hang.

Comment: I have tried that, but it dosent work. Can you show me that in my code?

Comment: Sure thing. If you're going to implement jQuery, you'll need to load a jQuery library dependency, that being a .js file. Put the following <script> tag in the <head> section or before the jQuery code: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`